# Set/get value for a trait

Tags: rust

I want to modify this *Rust/Substrate* code so that I can set the max value returned.  In one module, I have to set it to 500 and in another unit test mock runtime, to 1000.  I cannot modify the *Substrate* trait.  It would be great if I could have a companion `set_value(v)` function but that likely involves passing `&self` to both `set_value()` and `get_value()` which won't work. Is there a way around this?  Perhaps using macros?  What should I try?

```
// SUBSTRATE BEGIN
//
/// A trait for querying a single value from a type.
///
/// It is not required that the value is constant.
//
pub trait Get<T> {
    /// Return the current value.
    fn get() -> T;
}

impl<T: Default> Get<T> for () {
    fn get() -> T {
        T::default()
    }
}
// SUBSTRATE END

pub struct MaxRecordsTrait {
    value: u32,
}

impl MaxRecordsTrait {
    pub fn get_value() -> u32 {
        return 8000;
    }
}

impl Get<Option<u32>> for MaxRecordsTrait {
    fn get() -> Option<u32> {
        return Some(Self::get_value());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing that you have a _struct_ that is named with `Trait` as a suffix..

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking, but I suspect that you actually just want to use a different value in tests?

Comment: If so you can use `#[cfg(test)]` and `#[cfg(not(test))]`.